# Issue with `mclapply` in R package S4 implementation when passing strings

Tags: r, lapply, r-package, r-s4, mclapply

I am developing an R package that utilizes S4 classes and methods. In one of the methods, I am using `mclapply` from the `parallel` package to process data in parallel. This method has an if-else nest that checks a string argument and runs different internal functions accordingly.

The problem is that when I build the package and try to run the method, I get an error that the string value object doesn't exist, even though it's passed as a string. Surprisingly, when I use `lapply` instead of `mclapply`, everything works fine.

Here's a simplified example to illustrate my issue:

```
# External
out_function <- function(input_vector, condition_string="add_2") {
  result_list <- 
    parallel::mclapply(input_vector,
             function(i, condition_string_lapply=condition_string) {
               if (condition_string == "add_2") {
                 i <- in_add_2(i)
               } else if(condition_string == "add_3") {
                 i <- in_add_3(i)
               }
             }, mc.cores=3)
  result <- unlist(result_list)
  return(result)
}

# Internal
in_add_2 <- function(i) {
  return(i + 2)
}

# Internal
in_add_3 <- function(i) {
  return(i + 3)
}

final_result <- out_function(input_vector=seq(1, 10, 1),
                             condition_string="add_3")
```

Note: `out_function` is a public method in my package, while `in_add_2` and `in_add_3` are internal functions.

##### Error:

The error message I get is: `"add_2" object not found`

I also tried debugging with `debug()`, and it says `in_add_2` missing.

I am kind of confused about what I am doing wrong. How can I fix this issue so that `mclapply` recognizes the string as a string argument, not an object? Or is this related to the internal functions somehow?

Thank you for any help on this matter!

---

session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/Madrid
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] iCOBRA_1.28.0               DESeq2_1.40.1              
 [3] assertthat_0.2.1            Matrix_1.5-1               
 [5] sctransform_0.3.5           SeuratObject_4.1.3         
 [7] Seurat_4.3.0                gtools_3.9.4               
 [9] tradeSeq_1.14.0             my_package_1.0.2           
[11] lubridate_1.9.2             forcats_1.0.0              
[13] stringr_1.5.0               dplyr_1.1.3                
[15] purrr_1.0.2                 readr_2.1.4                
[17] tidyr_1.3.0                 tibble_3.2.1               
[19] ggplot2_3.4.3               tidyverse_2.0.0            
[21] SingleCellExperiment_1.22.0 SummarizedExperiment_1.30.1
[23] Biobase_2.60.0              GenomicRanges_1.52.0       
[25] GenomeInfoDb_1.36.0         IRanges_2.34.0             
[27] S4Vectors_0.38.1            BiocGenerics_0.46.0        
[29] MatrixGenerics_1.12.0       matrixStats_0.63.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] RcppAnnoy_0.0.20        TrajectoryUtils_1.8.0   slingshot_2.8.0        
  [4] splines_4.3.0           later_1.3.1             bitops_1.0-7           
  [7] polyclip_1.10-4         lifecycle_1.0.3         rstatix_0.7.2          
 [10] edgeR_3.42.2            doParallel_1.0.17       globals_0.16.2         
 [13] lattice_0.21-8          MASS_7.3-59             backports_1.4.1        
 [16] magrittr_2.0.3          limma_3.56.1            plotly_4.10.1          
 [19] shinyBS_0.61.1          httpuv_1.6.11           spatstat.sparse_3.0-1  
 [22] sp_1.6-0                reticulate_1.28         cowplot_1.1.1          
 [25] pbapply_1.7-0           minqa_1.2.5             RColorBrewer_1.1-3     
 [28] abind_1.4-5             zlibbioc_1.46.0         Rtsne_0.16             
 [31] RCurl_1.98-1.12         monocle3_1.3.1          GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.10
 [34] ggrepel_0.9.3           irlba_2.3.5.1           spatstat.utils_3.0-3   
 [37] listenv_0.9.0           terra_1.7-29            moments_0.14.1         
 [40] venn_1.11               goftest_1.2-3           spatstat.random_3.1-5  
 [43] fitdistrplus_1.1-11     parallelly_1.35.0       leiden_0.4.3           
 [46] codetools_0.2-19        DelayedArray_0.26.3     DT_0.28                
 [49] tidyselect_1.2.0        farver_2.1.1            lme4_1.1-33            
 [52] viridis_0.6.3           spatstat.explore_3.2-1  jsonlite_1.8.7         
 [55] ellipsis_0.3.2          progressr_0.13.0        ggridges_0.5.4         
 [58] survival_3.5-5          iterators_1.0.14        RColorConesa_1.0.0     
 [61] foreach_1.5.2           tools_4.3.0             ica_1.0-3              
 [64] Rcpp_1.0.11             glue_1.6.2              gridExtra_2.3          
 [67] mgcv_1.8-42             admisc_0.32             shinydashboard_0.7.2   
 [70] withr_2.5.1             fastmap_1.1.1           boot_1.3-28            
 [73] fansi_1.0.5             entropy_1.3.1           digest_0.6.33          
 [76] timechange_0.2.0        R6_2.5.1                mime_0.12              
 [79] colorspace_2.1-0        scattermore_1.1         tensor_1.5             
 [82] spatstat.data_3.0-1     UpSetR_1.4.0            utf8_1.2.3             
 [85] generics_0.1.3          data.table_1.14.8       httr_1.4.6             
 [88] htmlwidgets_1.6.2       S4Arrays_1.0.4          uwot_0.1.14            
 [91] pkgconfig_2.0.3         gtable_0.3.4            lmtest_0.9-40          
 [94] XVector_0.40.0          htmltools_0.5.5         carData_3.0-5          
 [97] scales_1.2.1            png_0.1-8               rstudioapi_0.14        
[100] tzdb_0.4.0              reshape2_1.4.4          nlme_3.1-162           
[103] nloptr_2.0.3            zoo_1.8-12              KernSmooth_2.23-20     
[106] miniUI_0.1.1.1          pillar_1.9.0            grid_4.3.0             
[109] vctrs_0.6.3             RANN_2.6.1              promises_1.2.0.1       
[112] ggpubr_0.6.0            car_3.1-2               xtable_1.8-4           
[115] cluster_2.1.4           princurve_2.1.6         cli_3.6.1              
[118] locfit_1.5-9.7          compiler_4.3.0          rlang_1.1.1            
[121] crayon_1.5.2            future.apply_1.10.0     ggsignif_0.6.4         
[124] labeling_0.4.3          mclust_6.0.0            plyr_1.8.8             
[127] stringi_1.7.12          deldir_1.0-9            viridisLite_0.4.2      
[130] BiocParallel_1.34.1     munsell_0.5.0           lazyeval_0.2.2         
[133] spatstat.geom_3.2-1     hms_1.1.3               patchwork_1.1.2        
[136] future_1.32.0           shiny_1.7.4             ROCR_1.0-11            
[139] igraph_1.4.2            broom_1.0.4
```

Comment: Getting `[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13`, works fine for me! You might add some `sessionInfo`. Maybe just doing `parallel::mclapply` solves the issue, just noticed that my respective edit might have influence on functionality.

Comment: @jay.sf Thanks for the response. I have attached the session info. And no, "parallel::mclapply" does not work either. As you pointed out, the function works normally, but when the package is built, it doesn't work.

Comment: You're aware that `parallel::mclapply` on Windows is only "available" if `mc.cores=1` but you hard coded `3`? Not sure though, what "available" actually means, currently no access to a Windows machine.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am running it on Ubuntu (session info attached). As far I know, "available" means the ability to fork. In Windows, "mclapply" works as "lapply" even if the mc.cores is > 1.

Comment: Aha, so you're running the package on your own machine. You have tons of packages loaded. Already tried in a `R --vanilla` session?

Comment: Yes, but when I call my package. It loads some of the packages as well in the session. For example, the mclapply is called by ```importFrom("parallel", "mclapply","detectCores", "makeCluster", "stopCluster")```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255665/discussion-between-sp29-and-jay-sf).